# Powershell incorrect running sequence

Tags: powershell, active-directory, licensing, createuser

Kinda new to powershell and trying to write scripts in general. Im trying to create a script that creates an AD user and then assigns that user a license.
However doesn't seem to matter what I do, the sync command I have doesnt execute before the waiting period; so it cant find the user to assign the license to.
Any ideas what Im getting wrong?

```
`$DCSync = 'DC01'

#Starts AD Sync
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $DCSync -scriptblock {
Import-Module ADSync
Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta
Write-Output "testing"
}

send-mailmessage -From "abc@test123.co.uk" -To "abcHelpdesk@test123.co.uk" -Subject "New user creation" -Body "Please connect to DC01 and authenticate to Office 365 to complete the user setup for $UserPrincipalName" -SmtpServer [REDACTED]
Start-Countdown -Seconds 5 -Message "Synchronizing changes to Office 365"

#Install-Module PowerShellGet
#Install-Module Microsoft.Graph -Scope CurrentUser
#Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser

Connect-MgGraph -Scopes User.ReadWrite.All, Organization.Read.All

$MgUserID = Get-MgUser -UserId "$EmailAddress"

Update-MgUser -UserId "$MgUserID" -UsageLocation GB

Set-MgUserLicense -UserId $MgUserID -AddLicenses @{SkuId = "6fd2c87f-b296-42f0-b197-1e91e994b900" } -RemoveLicenses @()`
```

Write-Outpost "testing" always prints after the ADsync commands

Creating a user - assigning a license to newly created user
It just errors out because its not syncing to AD using the command so the user doesn't 'exist' yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

- Try using `Start-Sleep` rather than `Start-Countdown`
- If it isn't asynchronous, you can try running `Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Delta` using the `-AsJob` parameter, and then retrieve the status of that job using a `while` loop and not proceeding until the job is completed
- If you have the e-mail address, then you can use a `while` loop to not proceed until the account is created, like:

```
while ($null -eq $MgUserID){

try {
$MgUserID = Get-MgUser -UserId "$EmailAddress"
}
catch {
$MgUserID = $null
}

Start-Sleep -Seconds 30

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I think I worked it out - pretty sure it was the start of my script has a function that is called 'Start-Countdown' for a progress bar and it was just starting the AD Sync but then immediately pausing it.

-AsJob on the ADsync sorted it 

Thanks :)